# Laravel Rules Unique if

Tags: php, laravel

I have some hard times with Laravel Rules (importing csv file).
I'm trying to use the Rule::unique function but when another field is not empty, for example:

```
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'code' => ['required', 'string', Rule::unique('product_gift_cards', 'code')],
            'pin' => ['nullable'],
            'sequence_number' => ['nullable']
        ];
    }
```

So this code, should be unique only when sequence_number is not filled. When sequence_number is filled with something, the code should not be unique. I have deleted the unique index in the database, so it will work if I write is as needed, any suggestions?

Comment: I would create my own rule, check out [`Using Rule Objects`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#using-rule-objects), so create your custom one, asking for `sequence_number` and then depending if it is present or not, make it unique or not

Answer (score 0):

These are the validation rules in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#available-validation-rules

Sadly there's no `unique_if` rule here.

One possible solution here is you have to validate it manually. You check if the input has file uploaded using `$this->hasFile('sequence_number')`.

```php
$code_rules = ['required', 'string'];

// Check if sequence_number is NOT uploaded
if (! $this->hasFile('sequence_number')) {
    $code_rules[] = Rule::unique('product_gift_cards', 'code');
}

return [
    'code' => $code_rules,
    'pin' => ['nullable'],
    'sequence_number' => ['nullable']
];
```

Comment: Hmm, could be a way, but get is not recognized as a function here. Cause it's an csv import

Comment: I would be very careful using this type of things, because you need to check all things related to `sequence_number`: is it present? is it not empty (that means no `null`, no `''`, no `' '`, etc, so you are doing a lot of validation)? And when you work with `Request`, never use `get`, but `input`, the source code itself tells you to not call `get`

Comment: Well I could check only if there is a number. But still cannot find a way to check another value here

Comment: I didn't know that `sequence_number` is a file. Because based on your naming I assumed that its a number.

Comment: But if you know what you're doing, based on my first answer you should be able to determine what to do now. Anyway I updated my answer above, kindly check if this is your intended solution.